# Login form with header location doesn't work properly

Tags: php, session, redirect, authentication

I'm a bit new to PHP, and I'm trying to do the following in a login form:
- index.php: Login (link to reglogin.php)
- reglogin.php: either registration or login. When logging in: check if email is in database. If so --> login and go to succes page. The redirect to the succes page doesn't work.

**index.php**

```
<?php session_start(); $page=(isset($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:"index"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
....
<body>
    <?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>

    <div class="content">
        <?php
        $frontpage="page/home.php";
        $page404="page/404.php";
        $folder="page/";

        if ($page=="index") {
            include_once($frontpage);
        }
        else {
            include_once((file_exists($folder.$page.".php"))?$folder.$page.".php":$page404);
        }
    </div>
</body>
```

**includes/header.php**

```
<div class="header">
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
            ?>
            <ul><li><a href="index.php?page=logout">Log out</a></li></ul>
        <?php
        }
        else { ?>
            <ul><li><a href="index.php?page=reglogin">Log in</a></li></ul>
        <?php }
        ?>    
</div>
```

**Reglogin.php**

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {  ?>
    <form method="post" action="index.php?page=logincheck" class="loginform">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="login_email" />
            <input type="text" name="login_password" />
            <input type="submit" name="login_submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
<?php } else { echo "U are already logged in"; } ?>
```

**Logincheck.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'includes/config.php';

    // if session['email'] doesn't exit    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['login_email']) && isset($_POST['login_password'])) {
                $login_email = $_POST['login_email'];
        $login_password= $_POST['login_password'];       

                    if (!empty($login_email) && !empty($login_password)) {
                        $query = 'SELECT Email, Password FROM tblregpersons
                                    WHERE Email="' . $login_email .  '"
                                    AND Password="' . $login_password .  '"';
                        if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
                            $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
                            if ($query_num_rows == 0) {
                                echo "invalid";
                            }
                            else {
                                $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['login_email'];
                                header('location: index.php?page=succes');
                                exit();
***// This redirect doesn't work. The page stays on logincheck.php.***
                            }                     
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "query failed";
                        }
                    }                
                    else {
                        echo "Please fill in an email/password";
                    }
            }
            else {
                echo "no post";
            }
    else {
        "U are already logged in";
    }
?>
```

I work with `$_SESSION['email']`, because I also have a registration form, and I link this 'email' session to the POSTs of the registration and login form.

What am I doing wrong in this redirection?

Comment: is $_SESSION['email'] already set from previous tests? you should add some code to show your flow, so add some `else { echo '#suitable explanations#'; }` as the only output you have is 'invalid' in the middle of loads of IF's

Comment: input 'login_email' twice??? second will overwrite the first

Comment: I'm sorry, the second input is an input type fault when I wanted to add this code to the post.

Comment: And I complete the else's, I didn't added it in the code. I will edit it

Comment: one more needed to test if the query fails http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: didn't see that one. Thanks. But still have a blank page logincheck.php

Comment: whats in index.php? >> action="index.php?page=logincheck"

Comment: I'll add my index.php. 

In the index.php, I have an include with my header. In this header, I have <p>Login</p> with a link to reglogin.php.

I'm sorry, this is my first post in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new version of logincheck.php - change your form to post direct to here

Since this is the only script being referenced, there should be no output and redirect should work

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'includes/config.php';

// if session['email'] doesn't exit
$error='';
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['login_email']) && isset($_POST['login_password']))
    {
        $login_email = $_POST['login_email'];
        $login_password= $_POST['login_password'];       

        if(!empty($login_email) && !empty($login_password))
        {
            $query = "SELECT Email, Password
                FROM tblregpersons
                WHERE Email='".mysql_real_escape_string($login_email)."'
                AND Password='".mysql_real_escape_string($login_password)."'";
            $query_run = mysql_query($query);
            if($query_run)
            {
                $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
                if($query_num_rows != 1)
                {
                    $error="invalid";
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['login_email'];
                    header("Location:index.php?page=success");
                    exit();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $error='sql error '.mysql_error();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $error="Please fill in an email/password";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $error="no post";
    }
}
else
{
    $error="U are already logged in";
}
header("Location:index.php?page=logincheck&error=".urlencode($error));
exit();

?>
```

Comment: your index page does no session checking. you need to add something like this `if( (isset($_SESSION['email'])) && ($_SESSION['email']!='') ) $frontpage="page/loggedin.php";`  so the user is taken there instead of page/home.php  Have you created a logout script too?

Comment: Thanks a lot! No, not yet. I know this is with session_destroy().

Comment: But when I have the header('location:index.php?page=succes'), my session exists. But when I go to index.php, the session doesn't exist anymore. Can I give the session within the header(location), or isn't this safe?
Something like this:
In logincheck.php:
header('location: index.php?page=succes&email=' . $_SESSION['email']);

And in index.php:
$login_email = $_GET['email'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $login_email;

Answer (score 2):

you can try ob_flush before calling header, may be some output getting print before header.
Also configure php to show all errors so you will get exact error.

Comment: showing all error will show you if your hitting the header redirect and output has already been generated

Comment: But if I do an echo "succes" before the header location, it shows my echo. Then why would my header location not work?

Answer (score 0):

Your index.php script is generating output BEFORE Logincheck.php can do its work.

```
<?php
session_start();
$page=(isset($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:"index";
if($page=='logincheck')
{
    include('logincheck.php');
}
else
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
....
<body>
    <?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>

    <div class="content">
    <?php
    $frontpage="page/home.php";
    $page404="page/404.php";
    $folder="page/";

    if($page=="index")
    {
        include_once($frontpage);
    }
    else
    {
        include_once((file_exists($folder.$page.".php"))?$folder.$page.".php":$page404);
    }
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
<?php
}
?>
```

Note: your question says Logincheck.php but your script implies logincheck.php

An alternate solution would be to post your form to logincheck.php and have it header locate to the appropriate page or default back to index.php with an error message

Comment: So it is better to do the logincheck on the reglogin.php?
Because when I add the code you wrote on top of the index (if ($page == 'logincheck') ... ), it still gives me a blank logincheck.php (the `header('location: index.php?page=succes');` still doesn't work.

Comment: Omg, it works!
I wrote `include('logincheck.php')` instead of `include('page/logincheck.php')`. Sorry I missed that.
Thanks alot!

Answer (score -1):

You must use the `session_start()` at the beginning of the page.

Comment: I do this, right? The upper code is from reglogin.php and de second part is logincheck.php

Answer (score -2):

Your script is not redirecting because you've already sent output in the beginning of your script.

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {  ?>
<form method="post" action="index.php?page=logincheck" class="loginform">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="login_email" />
        <input type="text" name="login_password" />
        <input type="submit" name="login_submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
< ?php } else { echo "U are already logged in"; } ?>
```

In your php.ini file edit output_buffering and give it the value of 4096 (Recommended) and this should sove your problem.

Comment: please state in which of the __two__ scripts that occurs and where?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that. You mean the echo "invalid"?

Comment: This is Reglogin.php, there is no header redirect here!! Its in Logincheck.php